# Direct Proof: Algebra Simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm trying to figure out how this question was simplified, can someone walk me through the algebra steps here?

Question: Use the direct proof method to prove that if $r$ is any rational number, then $3r^2-2r+4$ is rational.

Answer: (skipping suppositions and definitions)
Then, $$3r^2-2r+4 = 3(p/q)^2-2(p/q)+4 = (3p^2-2pq+4q^2)/q^2$$

I dont understand this step of simplification, an explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $r$ is rational, exists $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $q\neq0$, such that $r=\frac{p}{q}$, substitute $r$ with $\frac{p}{q}$ we have:

$$3(\frac{p}{q})^2-2\frac{p}{q}+4=3\frac{p^2}{q^2}-2\frac{pq}{q^2}+\frac{4q^2}{q^2}=\frac{3p^2-2pq+4q^2}{q^2}$$

Comment: I suppose what I don't understand is how 3(p/q)²-2(p/q)+4 results in 3(p²/q²)-2(pq/q²)+4q²/q²

Comment: @skepticalforever $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{pq}{q^2}$ and $4=4\cdot 1=4\frac{q^2}{q^2}$

Comment: This must just be a shortcoming in my algebra understanding as I was unaware that (p/q) = (pq/q²). I'll have to look into this, thanks for helping out

Comment: It's because of $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\cdot1=\frac{p}{q}\cdot\frac{q}{q}=\frac{pq}{q^2}$

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, though how do I know that 1 would be equal to q/q vs p/p? is it because the denominator is equal to 1? Sorry I feel embarrassed with my lack of understanding here

Comment: For any integer $z\neq 0$, we have $\frac{z}{z}=1$, and $p,q$ are just some random non-zero integers, thats why $\frac{p}{p}=\frac{q}{q}=1$

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this up for me

Comment: welcome, glad to help!